# Overloading constructors turns ambiguous

Tags: java, android

I have an overloaded constructor, which looks a bit like this:

```
public Constructor (enum e, View v, @Nullable CustomClass1) {}
public Constructor (enum e, View v, @Nullable CustomClass2) {}
```

So in normal operation, which constructor gets used is determined by the `ArrayList`. But when the `ArayList` is nulled, stuff (obviously) gets confusing.

Thing is, my `enum`s would be able to fix this (the top enum will always be `A` for instance, and the second one will always be `B`).

Is there a way to base which constructor is used on the enum in some way?

Comment: I strongly recommend using factory methods instead of constructors, which can help solve this problem.  (But the answer to your actual question is no; which constructor is used gets decided at _compile time_ and the enum can be chosen dynamically at runtime.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Factory methods. Could you maybe describe them briefly?

Comment: Add static methods to your class: `public static MyClass createA(View v, ArrayList<CustomClass1>) { return new MyClass(...) }` `public static MyClass createB(View v, ArrayList<CustomClass2>) { return new MyClass(...) }` Make your constructors private and do whatever dirty hacks you need to to get those distinguished internally.

Comment: Casting `null` to the right type should do the trick. Anyway if the argument is null, there should be no difference using one or the other, isn't it?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Would that be done like `((ArrayList<CustomClass#>) null)`?

Comment: That's genious, thank you so much!

Comment: @Timmiej93, the overload you posted is invalid regardless of the arguments you pass in, because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotOverload).

Comment: Good to know. It was just an example though, in the real thing there are nullable classes there that would take care of it then.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory design pattern for this. Here is an example in Java that explains it pretty well

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case,  [Jean-Baptiste Yunès](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719263/jean-baptiste-yun%c3%a8s)'s suggestion of casting `null` to the right type works perfectly.

```
Constructor(Enum, View, ((CustomClass1) null));
```

This will tell the constructor that the argument isn't just `null`, but it's something from the `CustomClass1`, that is null.

This might not be the right solution for you, based on what you're trying to do. I'd suggest checking out [Richard Sussan's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216394/5721694) as well, so you can check which method works best for you.